# How can I build log in my system correctly with Firestore Cloud collections?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to customers log in to only customer main page (MusteriAnaSayfa) and restaurant accounts log in only restaurant main page (RestoranAnaSayfa) but I can't it.

It's verifying usernames and passwords from Firestore, but I'm having a little bit of confusion when logging in.

Customers logged in customer page but can also access to restaurant page. I can't solve it.
Same goes for the Restaurant entrance.

```
            FirebaseFirestore db= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            CollectionReference customerRef = db.collection("Customer");
            CollectionReference restaurantRef = db.collection("Restaurant");

            user = txtUser.getText().toString(); 
            pass = txtPass.getText().toString();

            customerRef.whereEqualTo("email", user).whereEqualTo("password", pass).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && rbMusteri.isChecked()){
                        Intent intentMusteriGiris = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), MusteriAnaSayfa.class);
                        startActivity(intentMusteriGiris);
                    }
                }
            });

            restaurantRef.whereEqualTo("email", user).whereEqualTo("password", pass).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && rbRestoran.isChecked()){
                        Intent intentRestoranGiris = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), RestoranAnaSayfa.class);
                        startActivity(intentRestoranGiris);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Note: I have 2 radioButton for log in.

Comment: Please c heck the duplicate to see how you can solve this problem.